Counting items by statuses and changing counter on update
I am building a laravel website where I need to show how many items a courier has delivered, failed and in progress. I made a counter using Observer, but I don't know how to get the previous status of the item in the update of the Observer and can't decrement the value. How should it be done?
I know I could just make a SQL request and count each category but I'm worried it would lead to optimization issues.
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Item;
use App\Models\Courier;

class ItemObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Item "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Item $item)
    {
        //
        $courier = Courier::find($item->courier_id);
        $courier->update([$item->status => $courier->value($item->status) + 1]);
        $courier->save();
        $item->update(['status' => 'delivered']);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Item "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Item $item)
    {
        // Tried to use getOriginal, I am afraid it gets the initial value instead of previous
        $courier = Courier::find($item->courier_id);
        $courier->update([$item->status => $courier->value($item->getOriginal('status')) - 1]);
        $courier->update([$item->status => $courier->value($item->status) + 1]);
        $courier->save();
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Item "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(Item $item)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Item "restored" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function restored(Item $item)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the Item "force deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Item  $item
     * @return void
     */
    public function forceDeleted(Item $item)
    {
        //
    }
}


Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Show your code in details.

Added the code. I hoped for a direction like:"Laravel has X" or "You should use triggers in SQL" because my current code is essentially useless
